# Cannot call Passport local strategy

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, angular5, passport-local

I'm a beginner in Angular 5 and I'm currently working on an app. So in login module, the passport local strategy is not working and passport.authenticate function is not working, and I can't seem to find the problem in my code.

Now I am not sure what is wrong because there is no error on the console and the return is null every time. That's why I'm copy pasting a lot of code.

Code is attached below.

Server.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

// API file for interacting with MongoDB
const api = require('./routes/api');
const auth = require('./routes/auth_companies');

require('./models/passport');

// Parsers/middlewares
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(flash());

// Angular DIST output folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.use(express.static('public'));

// API location
app.use('/api', api);
app.use('/auth', auth);
// Express Session
app.use(session({
secret: 'secret',
saveUninitialized: true,
resave: true
}));

// Passport init
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Express Validator
app.use(expressValidator({
errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
  var namespace = param.split('.')
  , root    = namespace.shift()
  , formParam = root;

while(namespace.length) {
  formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
 }
return {
  param : formParam,
  msg   : msg,
  value : value
};
}
}));

// Connect Flash
app.use(flash());

// Global Vars
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
res.locals.user = req.user || null;
next();
});

// Send all other requests to the Angular app
//app.get('*', (req, res) => {
// res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
//});

// start the server
//app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
// console.log('server on port 3000');
//}); 


//Set Port
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

const server = http.createServer(app);
console.log(port);
server.listen(port, () => console.log(Running on localhost:${port}));
```

Passport.js file

```
        const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    const passport = require('passport');
    const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

    const User = require ('./reg_company');

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
      done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
      User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
      });
    });

    passport.use( new LocalStrategy(
      function(email, password, done) {
        console.log('9900---------------------------------', email)
       User.getUserByEmail(email, function(err, user){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(!user){
          return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown User'});
        }

        User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
          if(err) throw err;
          if(isMatch){
            return done(null, user);
          } else {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
          }
        });
       });
      }));

    passport.use('local.signup' , new LocalStrategy ({
      passReqToCallback : true ,
      emailfield:'email',
      passwordfield:'password'
    }, function(req, email, password, done){
      User.findOne({'email':email}, function(err, user){
        if (err)
        {
          return done(err);
        }

        if (user)
        {
          return done (null, false);
        }

        const newCompany=new User();
        newCompany.email = req.body.email;
        newCompany.password = req.body.passport;

        User.createUser(newCompany, function(err, user){
          if(err) throw err;
          console.log(user);
          return done(null, user);
        });

      })
    }) )
```

Mongo File

```
        const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const uri='mongodb://localhost/tourhubdb';
    mongoose.connect(uri);
    const db=mongoose.connection;
    const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

    //tourist Schema
    let company_reg_schema = mongoose.Schema({
        email:{
            type:String,
            require:true
        },
        password:
        {
            type:String,
            require:true
        }
    });

    let User = module.exports = mongoose.model('companies',company_reg_schema);

    module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback){
      bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
          bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
              newUser.password = hash;
              newUser.save(callback);
          });
      });
    }

    module.exports.getUserByEmail = function(email, callback){
      var query = {email: email};
      User.findOne(query, callback);
    }

    module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
      User.findById(id, callback);
    }

    module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
      bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch) {
          if(err) throw err;
          callback(null, isMatch);
      });
    }
```

Routes file

```
        const express = require("express");
    const router = express.Router();

      router.post('/login',function (req,res,next){
      passport.authenticate('local-login', function (err ,user ,info){
      })(req ,res ,next);
      });



      module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents here...wherever you're returning    done(null....) under 
   passport.use(), you could replace the null value with different errors for the different    done() calls and see which one invokes and why.